# Aggregate periods using recursive queries

Tags: teradata, recursive-query, teradata-sql-assistant

I need to merge overlapping periods (defined by FROM and TO variables) of sequential events (with identifier NUM) for each group (ID) with a "lookahead buffer", meaning that if the next period starts within the buffer zone, they should be merged.

For instance; in the following example the second event (NUM = 2) starts at time 13, which is within the buffer zone (10 + 5 = 15).

The tricky part here compared to other similar problems I've found is that although the buffer period has a fixed value for each event, this could potentially change if it is merged with an event (only backwards) that has a longer buffer period.

For instance; Event three is also merged to the same periods as event 1 and 2, and because the buffer periods of these events are longer. The following buffer zone should instead be (25 + 5 = 30), rather than (25 + 3 = 28), meaning the following event 4 should also be included in these periods as well.

Once again the buffer period of event 4 is also changed to 5. However, because 40 > 31+5, the last event is a separate observation.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(ID INTEGER, NUM INTEGER, FROM INTEGER, TO INTEGER, LOOKAHEAD INTEGER);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 1, 1,  10, 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 2, 13, 20, 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 3, 21, 25, 3);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 4, 29, 31, 3);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 5, 40, 50, 3);
```

Eventually, the result I need are two observations with the two "disjunct" periods;

```
(ID = 1, FROM = 1,  TO = 31)
(ID = 5, FROM = 40, TO = 50)
```

Naturally I initially thought I could create this "LOOKHEAD"-variable, by creating a new variable LOOKAHEAD2 that is the maximum of previous value of LOOKAHEAD2 and current value of LOOKAHEAD, conditional on FROM(this record) < (TO + LOOKAHEAD)(previous record) using OLAP functions. This doesn't really work however since it is a reference to itself...

Instead, I tried using recursive queries, where I start with the first event `(NUM = 1)`, and than recursively join the table with the next event `(root.NUM+1 = next.NUM)` conditional on `(root.TO + root.LOOKAHEAD > next.FROM)`, and also updating the LOOKAHEAD variable accordingly.

But I have never used recursive queries before, and I can't get it to join on the updated value of the LOOKAHEAD-value.

Does anyone know how to solve this with either recursive queries or other?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `RESET WHEN` window modifier in your analytic functions (`LAG` in Teradata 16, or `MAX` in earlier ones); don't use a recursive query.

Update:

```sql
DROP TABLE MY_TABLE;
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE MY_TABLE 
( id          INTEGER
, num         INTEGER
, from_value  INTEGER
, to_value    INTEGER
, lookahead   INTEGER
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 1, 1,  10, 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 2, 13, 20, 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 3, 21, 25, 3);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 4, 29, 31, 3);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 5, 40, 50, 3);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (2, 1, 1, 10, 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (2, 2, 20, 30, 15);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (2, 3, 40, 41, 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (2, 4, 100, 200, 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (2, 5, 300, 400, 3);


SELECT  id, first_from_value, to_value
FROM  ( SELECT  id
              , to_value
              , CASE WHEN overlaps_flag = 1
                  THEN  NULL
                  ELSE  COALESCE 
                        ( MIN (from_value) 
                            OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                  ORDER BY from_value
                                  RESET WHEN MAX (overlaps_flag) 
                                               OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                                     ROWS BETWEEN 
                                                          1 PRECEDING 
                                                      AND 1 PRECEDING) = 0
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                           AND 1 PRECEDING)
                        , from_value )
                END AS first_from_value
        FROM  ( SELECT  id, from_value, to_value
                      , MAX (from_value) 
                          OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                ORDER BY from_value 
                                ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
                          AS next_from_value
                      , CASE WHEN to_value + lookahead + 1 >= next_from_value
                          THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                        END AS overlaps_flag
                FROM  my_table
              ) AS a
      ) AS a
WHERE first_from_value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

```
id  first_from_value    to_value
1   1                   31
1   40                  50
2   1                   10
2   20                  41
2   100                 200
2   300                 400
```

Comment: I solve it after exporting using another language. I looked at RESET WHEN, which I didn't know before, thanks. I still can't see how it will solve the problem however. If you want to I'd gladly look at your solution.