# How to order date ranges sequentially and remove overlaps in Teradata

Tags: time, teradata, date-range, overlapping, teradata-sql-assistant

I've got a list of date ranges with period start, and period end. Period end is chosen to be 3 months after the period start date

An example of the data is below:

`Row |Period start | Period end`
`1   |2018-01-01   | 2018-04-01`
`2   |2018-01-05   | 2018-04-05`
`3   |2018-04-02   | 2018-07-01`
`4   |2018-05-02   | 2018-08-02`
`5   |2018-09-10   | 2018-12-09`

I want the period start and end to be ordered sequentially, and remove cases where there is overlap in date ranges

The solution for this example is:

`Row |Period start | Period end`
`1   |2018-01-01   | 2018-04-01`
`3   |2018-04-02   | 2018-07-01`
`5   |2018-09-10   | 2018-12-09`

To explain the logic of what I'm trying to achieve:

The row 1 period end is 2018-04-01, and I want to be able to only include the next row where period start is strictly greater than this. I.e. row 3 with 2018-04-02.

Once 2018-04-02 is selected as the subsequent row, I want the next row after this to be outside of the period end range of (2018-07-02). I.e. it would be row 5 since 2018-09-10 falls outside of 2018-07-01

Is there a solution to be able to do this? (without having to recursively do it)

Comment: Do you want to actually delete the rows from the table, or exclude them from the output of a query?

Comment: BTW, I don't think this will be possible without recursion, or a stored proc using a cursor.

Comment: I just want them to be flagged so that I can exclude them from the output of a query

Comment: I've solved the problem using a stored proc and a while loop

Answer (score 0):

In Teradata, you may use `RESET WHEN` clause; [here you may find an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879557/aggregate-periods-using-recursive-queries/52353644#52353644) of solving a somewhat similar problem.