# Calculate overlapping time across multiple records

Tags: datetime, teradata

I would like to calculate overlapping time over multiple records. I am trying to do this using an analytical window function but am now stuck.

The data set:

```
ID  FY  WK  Group   StartDate   StartTime   EndTime Category    Dur Overlap
1   19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/03  22:35:00    23:25:00    MBA2    50  00:00:00
2   19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/04  09:40:00    09:55:00    MBD2    15  00:00:00
3   19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/04  10:30:00    10:55:00    MBD2    25  00:00:00
4   19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/04  13:50:00    14:30:00    MBD2    40  00:00:00
5   19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/04  14:05:00    15:15:00    MBD2    70  00:25:00
6   19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/04  19:30:00    01:20:00    MBA2    350 00:00:00
7   19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/06  08:45:00    09:30:00    MBD2    45  00:00:00
8   19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/06  17:30:00    21:40:00    MBA2    250 00:00:00
9   19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/06  19:30:00    20:10:00    MBA2    40  02:10:00
10  19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/07  00:00:00    01:20:00    MBA2    80  00:00:00
11  19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/07  08:30:00    09:20:00    MBD2    50  00:00:00
12  19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/07  09:20:00    16:20:00    MBD2    420 00:00:00
13  19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/07  13:30:00    13:46:00    MBD2    16  02:50:00
14  19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/07  16:06:00    16:20:00    MBD2    14  00:00:00
15  19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/07  17:45:00    23:00:00    MBA2    455 00:00:00
16  19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/07  20:30:00    21:20:00    MBA2    50  00:50:00
17  19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/07  22:30:00    22:45:00    MBA2    15  00:15:00
18  19  49  H-IS02  2019/06/07  23:00:00    23:15:00    MBA2    15  00:00:00
```

I set my partition to (Group, StartDate, Category) and want to calculate the overlap of the EndTime to the StartTime of the previous record IF it belongs to the same data set which is: StartDate, Group, Category.

The duration (Dur) is calculating fine but I also need to know the overlapping minutes for records in the same data set. Record 5 in the data above has a StartTime earlier than the EndTime for record 4 AND it belongs to the same partition.

[Calculation logic explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9u2Q.png)

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to approach this calculation.

Some more detail to the challenge: The data is for equipment at a plant. Each record contains the downtime information. I want to calculate the duration a machine overlapped the downtime of another piece of machinery. Two machines could've been down at the same time - with the exact start and finish times. So if their downtime was an hour long each my total downtime was 2 hours and my effective downtime was 1 hour only. By calculating the overlap of downtime between machines I can also determine the EFFECTIVE DOWNTIME as TOTAL DOWNTIME - OVERLAP

I first approached this problem by using a partition but don't think it'll solve my problem. The challenge as I see it is that I may for example have 4 records which should be checked for an overlap. Record 2 is an overlap of record 1. Record 3 doesn't overlap anything and record 4 overlaps record 1. If the offset was always 1 or n records I could use the LAG function.

My current SELECT statement is below. And it doesn't give me a warm feeling either... It creates extra records in the result set.

```
    select DT.fiscalyear, DT.productionweek, DT.group, DT.plantsection, DT.startdate, DT.category,OL.endtime,OL.starttime, 
dt.endtime,DT.starttime, dt.endtime - DT.starttime as Overlap 
from (
select DT.fiscalyear, DT.productionweek, DT.group, DT.PlantSection, DT.StartDate, DT.starttime,dt.MaintenancePlant, 
        DT.EndDate, DT.endtime, DT.category, DT.breakdownduration 
from Labs_Engineering.BV_MOR_Mining_AllDowntime DT) DT

join (
select TEST.startdate, PlantSection,category, max(endtime) endtime, max(starttime) starttime
from Labs_Engineering.BV_MOR_Mining_AllDowntime Test
where productionweek = 49 and fiscalyear = 19
and MaintenancePlant = 9804
and group = 'H-IS02'
and category like 'MBA2'
and (PlantSection ='P33' or PlantSection = 'P34')
group by PlantSection,category,startdate
--where DT.endtime <= Test.starttime
) OL
on DT.StartDate = OL.StartDate
and DT.PlantSection = OL.PlantSection
and DT.category = OL.category
where DT.starttime <= OL.endtime and ol.starttime > dt.starttime;
```

Comment: Please format your table data so it is _readable_ (we can't read it right now).

Comment: please [edit] your post to add a screenshot of the dataset. remove the dataset text from your post.

Comment: Yeah - I'm trying to get it into a readable format :)

Comment: Can you show your existing Select?

Comment: @dnoeth I added some more detail and my current SELECT statement

Comment: Your final reuslt should be the overall downtime? Regarding the example data, the end time might be next day? See ID 6: Start 19:30:00  End 01:20:00

Comment: In Teradata, you may use `RESET WHEN` clause; here you may find an example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879557/aggregate-periods-using-recursive-queries/52353644#52353644 of solving a somewhat similar problem.